# Classes are getting duplicated when running flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

It's been 3 days since I am facing this issue and I tried many things but I wasn't able to solve it. I already upgraded all gradlew to 8.0 and nothing succeeded. I thought it had to do with in_app_review but I couldn't find any relation with it.

I tried upgrading all my dependencies but it keeps returning the error.
I already cleaned all the cache, deleted all folders from gradlew and change my firebase ads dependence because I am using it.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkHmlDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.IntentSenderForResultStarter found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.LocalTestingException found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.PlayCoreDialogWrapperActivity found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.listener.StateUpdatedListener found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewInfo found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManager found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManagerFactory found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.testing.FakeReviewManager found in modules jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)
```

this is my pubspeck:

```
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'
version: 2.6.1+261

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1

  #novas libs
  android_id: ^0.1.3+1
  battery_plus: ^3.0.2
  #device_apps: ^2.2.0
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  global_configuration: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.1
  firebase_remote_config: ^3.0.4
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  firebase_app_check: ^0.1.1+8
  firebase_analytics: ^10.1.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.0.11
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.11
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1
  freshchat_sdk: ^0.10.2
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  mobx: ^2.0.7
  flutter_mobx: ^2.0.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.16
  dio: ^4.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.2
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.7
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  local_auth: ^2.1.3
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  transparent_image: ^2.0.0
  clipboard: ^0.1.3
  qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1
  share: ^2.0.4
  file_picker: ^5.0.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.8.3
  flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6+1
  advance_pdf_viewer_fork: ^2.0.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2
  contacts_service: ^0.6.3
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  network_info_plus: ^3.0.1
  image_cacheing: ^0.0.2
  facebook_app_events: ^0.18.3
  crypto: ^3.0.1
  in_app_review: ^2.0.6
  camera: 0.10.1
```

Comment: did you already try recreating the project from scratch, and bring the dependencies one by one - see what's causing the issue?

Comment: Same issue here, I get duplication alerts for this package
Exact same error than you. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but the *in_app_review* package was causing the problem.

You can try lock *in_app_review: 2.0.4* and see if the conflict persist

Comment: how was it causing a problem? How did you solve the problem specifically?

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/britannio/in_app_review/issues/85
For me, there was a conflict between in_app_update and in_app_review when I updated my pubspeck. 
Locking it to in_app_review 2.0.4 solved the problem.